# Need to achieve 5000 concurrent api hits on AWS using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

We are currently trying to achieve 5000 TPS hit for one of our API. We are using Mongo Atlas 3.2.12 and NodeJS v6.10.2, on every hit it hits DB with 3 find queries. There is an ELB in place and behind the ELB there are two instances of Amazon EC2 type medium. Using Apache Benchmark tool we figured out that in a second it is only handling the 68 hits.

Below is the Apache Benchmark tool's output -

```
Document Length:        748 bytes

Concurrency Level:      1000
Time taken for tests:   116.294 seconds
Complete requests:      5000
Failed requests:        4274
   (Connect: 0, Receive: 0, Length: 4274, Exceptions: 0)
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      5440980 bytes
HTML transferred:       3830980 bytes
Requests per second:    42.99 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       23258.823 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       23.259 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          45.69 [Kbytes/sec] received

Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        6  418 823.7     10    2448
Processing:   197 21032 7150.3  21848   35739
Waiting:      197 21031 7150.3  21848   35739
Total:        205 21450 7264.9  22052   36744

Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%  22052
  66%  24953
  75%  26697
  80%  27814
  90%  30272
  95%  31804
  98%  33428
  99%  34534
 100%  36744 (longest request)
```

EDIT: We are already using multi-cluster. But we are not able to achieve the desired TPS which is 2000 in a second.  Currently, we have upgraded the server from t2 medium to m4-large. Any suggestion would be a great help.

Please suggest the changes and architecture.

Comment: What's your architecture?

Answer (score 1):

Your bottleneck is clearly nodeJS.
Node manages concurrency with an event stack running in a single thread, this is great for APIs that spend most of the time waiting for IO to end since the main process is not blocked and the events in the stack are popped once the task has been finished.
The problem with this architecture is when multiple simultaneous mid-load connections gets into the server at the same time leading to a problem known as resource starvation. In this case, the event stack gets more and more entries and the loop can't handle them all in a proper why, slowing the process and even causing heap overflow or unexpected shutdowns.

To fix this **without knowing your architecture,** i'd recomend to switch to a more mature (from the tecnical point of view) tecnologies like Go, splitting your DB and API, setting up multiple stateless API processes and having a load balancer to redirect the calls to the less busy API instance.

would be great to have more info about your architecture tho.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend changing the foundation architecture since there are better options available, such as Node Cluster.

Comment: @AliAshraf, i totally agree, but i have to recomend what i would do since OP didn't gave us any detail, he could already be using node cluster, i just went to "a good approach" instead of trying to fix an unknown arch

Answer (score 0):

As AB results in Each request taking around 23 Second (Mean). Have you observe any load or RAM spike on API server. You can increase node workers or servers to handle more request.

`Time per request:       23258.823 [ms] (mean)`

Imp. Check time consume by a single query on DB is there any index is present or not?

Comment: all query fields has an index and we have increased thread pool using UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE  to 128 but not seen any differences.

Comment: First you have you check how much success request your app can handled on  t2 medium/m4-large single instance. corresponding you can increase number of instance. And have you checked latency on load-balancer metrics Some time our application taking time more to response for each call and calls were fails because of RTO. May be that’s helpful. You can contact me directly Happy to help on this

Answer (score 0):

Use Node Cluster if you have a multi core processor and see what happens.

https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_cluster

Example of usage in this article: https://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-a-node-js-cluster-for-speeding-up-your-apps/

Comment: We are already using multi-cluster. But we are not able to achieve the desired TPS which is 2000 in a second.  Currently, we have upgraded the server from t2 medium to m4-large. Any suggestion would be a great help.

Answer (score 0):

Cant you setup your architecture to use something like docker, swarm, ucp and just scale up? You have a master and as many slaves as you need to scale.